# Все записи созданные или обновлённые в бд MySQL за год

Tags: mysql

Подскажите есть ли решение следующего вопроса. Есть множество баз с данными и в таблицах нет колонок с датой создания или модификации. Нужно получить число записей, обновлённых или добавленных за прошлый год. Вроде где-то ранее натыкался что эта информациях хранится во внутренней базе мускула.